# Borel isomorphism between polish spaces

Tags: probability, measure-theory

In my lecture on stochastics the following result has been used:

For any uncountable Polish space $X$ there is a Borel isomorphism between this space and the real line.

I was not able to find a proof of this in the internet, other than in a book of Srivastava: "A course on borel sets". But the proof uses instruments that are far beyond my possibilities.

Is there any "simple" proof of this fact?

Comment: One way I can think of: every separable metric space embeds homeomorphically in $(0,1)^{\bf N}$, $(0,1)^{\bf N}$ embeds in a Borel way in $2^{\bf N}$ (I think something like standard binary expansion should give you that), and $2^{\bf N}$ embeds homeomorphically into every uncountable Borel set (I don't remember if that's difficult...). These facts together tell you that you can find Borel embeddings both ways. Finally, a fairly standard argument shows that you have a Cantor-Bernstein theorem for Borel embeddings.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following result is given as Theorem 8.3.6 in Cohn's *Measure Theory*:

> Let $A$ and $B$ be Borel subsets of Polish spaces. Then $A$ and $B$ are Borel isomorphic if and only if they have the same cardinality. Furthermore, the cardinality of each uncountable Borel subset of a Polish space is that of the continuum.

The first statement of the theorem is rather straightforward. The "furthermore part" requires a bit more work, but is still rather "simple". Since I am not able to give a short, self-contained proof I would like to refer to the excellent proof in Cohn's book.